# Java3D setup - MacOSx

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, installation, java-3d

When trying to run a basic HelloUniverse program, i get the following error.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/media/opengl/GLCapabilitiesChooser
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at javax.media.j3d.Pipeline$1.run(Pipeline.java:162)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.media.j3d.Pipeline.createPipeline(Pipeline.java:157)
at javax.media.j3d.MasterControl.loadLibraries(MasterControl.java:965)
at javax.media.j3d.VirtualUniverse.<clinit>(VirtualUniverse.java:299)
at HelloUniverse.init(HelloUniverse.java:55)
at com.sun.j3d.utils.applet.MainFrame.run(MainFrame.java:267)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
javax.media.opengl.GLCapabilitiesChooser
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 10 more
```

I can't seem to find a solution to get Java3D working on mac.

Comment: What version of java and java3d are you using?

Comment: @jjhavokk
Java3d 1.5.1 and jdk 1.8

Comment: I don't think Java3D works with Oracle's JRE.  (Also, please note that Java3D is pretty much an abandoned project.  You would be much better off putting your learning effort into JOGL.)

Comment: @whiskeyspider Java3D isn't an abandoned project, it's actively maintained by the JogAmp community (that maintains JOGL 2 too by the way). (Oracle) Java3D 1.5 is abandoned and no longer maintained. Please rather use (JogAmp's) Java3D 1.6 with JOGL 2. You can follow my instructions here: http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Downloading_and_installing_Java3D Moreover, applets have been deprecated in Java 1.9 and will be removed from Java 1.10, I advise you not to use them.